# English Exodus Rabbah

Tags: product-recommendation, midrash, internet

Is anyone aware of a full text of Shemos Rabbah in English available online? Sefaria has bits and pieces, but I'd like the full thing.

Comment: The Soncino Press Translated the whole work back in the day, I’d look into that. Art scroll also translated it, I don’t know if they have digital copies for sale.

Comment: Art Scroll has a translation of the entire Midrash Rabbah in English. If you are willing to spend money, I would recommend it.